# C++ compiling error expected identifier before numeric constant

Tags: c++

I have the following declaration in a header file

```
extern int myfunction  (DEBUG *debug, DOMAIN *dom, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2);
```

When Compiling I get the following error.

```
expected identifier before numeric constant
expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

please help.

Comment: What is a `DEBUG`? What is a `DOMAIN`?

Comment: DEBUG and DOMAIN are structures not defined in this header file. It is defined in another header file.

Comment: I suspect `DEBUG` is #defined as 0 or 1 somewhere.

Comment: Try the `-E` flag to see what this looks like after preprocessing as in `g++ -E myfile.cpp`  You will likely see this change to `extern int myfunction(0 *debug, DOMAIN *dom, ...`.  Though it's also possible the DEBUG macro is set somewhere in the build system.

Comment: do you get the same error with any line containing DEBUG? `int main() { DEBUG d; }`  Does debug effectively function as an int? `int main() { int i = DEBUG; }`  You could also try adding a `#undef DEBUG` to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

`DEBUG` is a commonly set `#define-d` value; it's probably getting replaced with `1` (or less likely, `0`) by the preprocessor.